# Calling an api in python giving me an InvalidChunkLength error, what do I do?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use the Frankfurter currency exchange rate API in my python program but it is returning *InvalidChunkLength* error or *ChunkedEncodingError(e)* error when I try to print the status code to confirm that the connection is established.

I have tried the suggestion in this answer and it did not work: [requests - ChunkedEncodingError with requests.get, but not when using Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70189517/requests-chunkedencodingerror-with-requests-get-but-not-when-using-postman)

Here is my code:

```
import requests

convert_from = str(input("Enter the currency to convert from: ")).upper()
convert_to =  str(input("Enter the currency to convert to: ")).upper()
convert_amount= float(input("Enter the amount that you want to convert: "))
host = 'api.frankfurter.app'
response = requests.get(f'https://{host}/latest?amount={convert_amount}&from={convert_from}&to={convert_to}')

print(response.status_code)
```

My error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mysystem\Desktop\PYTHON\MyProjects\currency\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 748, in _update_chunk_length
    self.chunk_left = int(line, 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: b''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mysystem\Desktop\PYTHON\MyProjects\currency\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 443, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "C:\Users\Mysystem\Desktop\PYTHON\MyProjects\currency\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 815, in read_chunked
    self._update_chunk_length()
  File "C:\Users\Mysystem\Desktop\PYTHON\MyProjects\currency\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 752, in _update_chunk_length
    raise InvalidChunkLength(self, line)
urllib3.exceptions.InvalidChunkLength: InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read)
```

...and a bunch of lines.
Please note that when requests for just the api.frankfurter.app, it returns 200 as expected. Also, note that I am using a virtual environment on a Windows 11 machine.

Thank you for your help, I am pretty new to Python.